# Firebase: Obtener un hijo que está varios niveles por debajo de la referencia

Tags: android, firebase

En mi BD tengo 3 niveles (Empresa/xx/yyy) hasta llegar a los datos.

```
Empresa
     -LwfCTRVSlVzSdF5yyjz
       021
          nombre: Empresa21
     -LwfJ1UwR9rIVnQKHjFp
       031
          nombre: Empresa31
       032
          nombre: Empresa32
```

y me conecto con la siguiente llamada:

```
databaseReference.child("Empresa");
```

a partir de aquí si quisiera recuperar el hijo `021` ¿Como debería hacer la consulta?
He probado con lo siguiente pero no me devuelve nada:

```
BDreferencia.orderByKey().equalTo("021").addListenerForSingleValueEvent...
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: En Firebase puede alcanzar una ruta poniéndola tal cual: `Empresa/02/021` si ya conoces el destino no tienes que usar equal, order, where, etc porque ya sabes a dónde quieres llegar.

Comment: Mi pregunta es, ¿hay necesidad de una clave autogenerada? Puedes usar `Empresa21`, `Empresa31`... como clave y al mismo tiempo usarla para acceder a sus hijos, por ejemplo: `Empresa21/nombre`

Comment: Si, puedes usar la clave que vos quieras, la mayoria de veces es mas comodo usar una clave autogenerada, pero si ya generaste el id en otro lado, podes usarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el padre de donde esta ubicado nombre podes usar `getKey()`

```
BDreferencia.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
          String key = snapshot.getKey();
          String nombre = snapshot.child("nombre").getValue(String.class);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }
    });
```

`BDreferencia` deberia hacer referencia al id de la empresa

```
DatabaseReference BDreferencia;
BDreferencia.child("Empresa").child(empresaID);
```